# "Zaubern mögen sie, soviel sie wollen"

Tags: subjunctive, modal-verb

This post is on *mögen* as found in the following sentence from *Zwist unter Zauberern* by Kurt Kusenberg.  (For context, see the photo at the bottom of this post.)

> Zaubern **mögen** sie, soviel sie wollen, jegliches Verwandeln und Behexen steht ihnen frei, aber sie dürfen nichts Lebendiges vernichten.

[The Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%B6gen) on *mögen* lists these two uses among others.

> 3 (*auxiliary, with infinitive*) may (*expresses a possibility, never a permission*)
>     *Das mag ja alles stimmen. ― That may all be true.*
>   
>   5 (*auxiliary, in the present subjunctive, with infinitive*) may (*paraphrases the optative*).
>     *Möge die Macht mit dir sein. ― May the Force be with you.*

**QUESTION**

Should I assimilate the use of *mögen* in the Kusenberg story to case 3 or 5?

I note that *mögen* is both Indikativ Präsens Aktiv and Konjunktiv I Präsens Aktiv, for third person plural.

The sentence seems to say, 'Let them do as much magic as they pleased. . . .'  So one might think it paraphrases the optative (as Wiktionary puts it), or case 5.

But *steht*, which extends the idea, is in the indicative, which may argue for case 3.

**BACKGROUND**

Photo of the story:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, Wiktionary, if only you were as accurate as you are confident when you say *expresses a possibility, never a permission*. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/m%C3%B6gen) says (and that entry is derived from [WDG](https://www.dwds.de/d/wdg), a proper dictionary):

> 3. *in Verbindung mit einem Infinitiv; nur im Präs.; der Sprecher ist nie grammatisches Subj.*
> **drückt aus, dass der Sprecher nicht gegen die Realisation des Inhaltes des Inf. ist, dass er bereit ist, sie hinzunehmen**
> Beispiele:
> er mag das Buch behalten
> das mag er halten, wie er will
> mögen sie nur kommen (ich fürchte mich nicht)!
> es mag kommen, was (da) will, ich bleibe bei meinem Entschluss
> Dein Tapp, der hier trübselig im Schnee sitzt, mag sich an meinem Küchenfeuer wärmen [C. F. Meyer, 4,12]

[DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=moegen) has this meaning as well (under II. 7.):

> **a)** mögen *einfach erlaubt sein, berechtigung bezeichnend:* den (kauf) magstu behalten.
>
> […]
>
> **c)** *dieses erlaubt sein, freistehen, mit dem beisinne der gleichgiltigkeit für einen andern oder für einen bestimmten zweck:* er mag es thun *(es steht ihm frei zu thun, aber mir ist es einerlei); auch ausrufend:* mag ers doch thun!; mag er bleiben, wo er will!; mag er kommen oder gehn, was schierts mich?

This meaning – **permission out of, or tinged with, indifference** – fits really well with the following two sentences that have *freistehen* and *nicht dürfen*: They cover what wizards are allowed to do and what not, and I therefore think that this reading is the correct one.

The interpretation as an optative is far-fetched. As you point out yourself, it would clash with the two following indicatives. Optatives are exceedingly rare in modern-day German and the narrator betrays no sign of expressing a wish, he is merely stating facts.

Comment: Just to make it explicit, the answer is: "Neither 3 nor 5, but a case permission (subject to 5 not being absolutely ruled out)"?

Comment: @Catomic I was being squeamish about rejecting the optative. I think that reading can be ruled out, as far as any reading can be ruled out; it is as unlikely as 3.